# air traffic controller for threads when calling a REST API

Tags: multithreading, rest, scheduled-tasks, daemon

DISCLAIMER:  If this post is off-topic to this site, please recommend a site where this post would be appropriate.

On Ubuntu 18.04, in bash, I am writing a network-based, threaded application that requires multiple servers.  It receives files through the network and processes them, ultimately making an API call that finishes the processing and logs the results to a database for later retrieval and reporting.

So far I have written the application using non-threaded programming models and concepts.  That means the files are processed one at a time in real-time.  This works great if there is no sudden burst of files and/or a backlog of files to process.  The main bottle neck has been the way I sequentially send files to the API one after another, waiting until the entire operation has taken place for one file and the API returns the results.  The API has a rate limit of 8 calls per second.  But since each call takes from .75 to 1 second, my program waits until the operation is done and only processes about 1 file per second through the API.  In short, I did not have to worry about scheduling API calls because I could barely do one call per second.

Since the capacity is there to process 8 files per second, and I need more speed, I have been converting my single-threaded, sequential application into a parallel, scalable, multi-threaded application.  This new version can spawn enough threads to send 8 files per second to the REST API and much more.  So now I have the opposite problem.  I am sending too many requests per second to the REST API and am in danger of triggering penalties, etc.  Ultimately, when my traffic is higher, I will upgrade my subscription to the API and get more calls per second, but this current dilemma has got me thinking about how to schedule the API calls with different threads.

The purpose of this post is to discuss an idea about how to schedule these REST API calls across various threads.  Specifically, I want to discuss how to coordinate timing and usage of the API while maintaining efficiency and yet not overloading the API.  In short, I want to coordinate a group of threads so that the API is properly used.  Not too fast and not too slow.

Independent of my application, this idea could be useful in a number of generically similar scenarios.

My idea is to create an "air traffic controller" ("ATC") so that the threads of the application have a centralized timing authority to check when they are ready to submit files to the REST API.  The ATC would know how many time slots/calls per time period (in this case, calls per second) the API can schedule.  The ATC would be listening for the threads to request a time slot ("launch code") which would give them a time slot in the future to perform their API call.  The ATC would decide based on the schedule of other launch codes that it has already handed out.

In my case, from the start of the upload of the file to the API, it could take 0.75 to 1 second to complete the processing and receive a response from the API.  This does not affect the count of new API calls that can be performed.  It is just a consideration of how long the threads will be waiting once they call the API.  It may not be relevant to this overall discussion.

Each thread would obviously have to do some error handling.  If the API timed out or threw an error, then the thread would have to handle it and get back in line with the ATC -if appropriate- and ask for a new launch code.  Maybe it should report the error to the ATC for centralized logging?

In situations where the file processing needs burst above 8 files per second, there would be a scheduling backlog where the threads should wait their turn as assigned by the ATC.

Here are some other considerations:

Function

The ATC would be a lightweight daemon that does the following:
  - listens on some TCP port
  - receives a request
       security token (?), thread id, priority
  - authenticates the request (?)
  - examines schedule
  - reserves the next available time slot
  - returns the launch code
       security token (?), current time, launch timing offset to current time, URL and auth token for the API
  - expunged expired launch codes

The ATC would need the following:
  - to know what port it is supposed to run on
  - to know how many slots per time period it was set to schedule
        (e.g. 8 per second)
  - to have a super fast read/write access to the schedule (associative array?)
  - to know the URL and corresponding auth token for the thread to use
  - maybe to know multiple URLs and auth tokens for load balancing

Here are more things to consider:

1. Security
   How could we keep the ATC secure while ensuring high performance?
   Network-level security (e.g. firewalls allowing only the IP addresses of the file-processing servers?)
   Auth tokens or logins and passwords?
2. Performance
   What would the requirements be for this ATC server?  Would this be taxing to a CPU and memory?
3. Timing
   How often would an NTP call be needed?  By the ATC server?  By the servers which call the API?
4. Scalability
   Being able to provide different URLs and auth tokens would allow the ATC to load balance with different API providers.
5. Threading of the ATC itself
   Would the ATC need to spawn threads to be able to handle each new request?
   How does a web server handle requests?
   How would the various threads share a common schedule?
   In a non-threaded environment, the ATC would possibly keep an associative array in memory to keep performance as high as possible.  How would the various threads of the ATC have access to the same schedule?

So here is my question.  Does this exist?  If not, what are some best practices in trying to build the above?

It seems like a beanstalkd kind of network service except it only provides permission/scheduling and is extremely dependant on timing.

Comment: What language are you using for this? Many have facilities to do exactly what you want but way simpler. There's a few bits here that suggest maybe PHP and PHP has curl_multi that can handle multiple asynchronous requests and rate limiting. Why would you need NTP??

Comment: The language would possibly be C for the daemon and the threads are written in bash.  I'm open to whatever.  I just need a push in the right direction.  I will look into PHP and curl_multi.  NTP is to make sure that the thread servers and the ATC server are synced to the exact same time so that when the ATC says in the launch codes, "Hey, you can launch at 10:53:07.125", then they both (ATC and thread on a different server) are talking about the exact same time.  The thread can then do a ```sleepuntil``` like command and launch at the correct time.

Comment: I would _strongly_ suggest you go with a simple scripting language and try to find an existing solution. Your solution is inventive but this is a solved problem and the solution in for example node.js is just a few lines of code.

Comment: Also 8 request per second is very little and does not require anything fancy.

Comment: I didn't notice it in your question, so I'll just add it here.. keywords to look for "Throttling parallel HTTP requests'.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and thoughts.  PHP's curl_multi seems like a way to load up eight tasks at a time and fire them at once.  Then I could wait a second and do it again.  That's crazy enough it just might work.  There would be some slack in the process due to waiting for the eight files to make it to that point.  Looking up "Throttling parallel HTTP requests" provides a lot of insights into the way the APIs look at it.  There is some discussion of throttling from the client side which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I want to avoid 429 errors and having to write the threads to handle those.  I WILL write them to be able to handle 429 errors, but I do not want a big pile up of threads timing out and retrying, all trying to cram their upload through the REST API and just have the luck of the draw as to which of the threads gets through.  I want to control the timing of threads.  And yes "8 threads" is small potatoes.  But this could scale to how ever many threads are needed.

Comment: None of that says it is a good idea or would work well, but I am still not seeing a complete solution.  Maybe an outbound HTTP proxy with round robin throttling?  But that still does not prevent pile-ups of threads waiting to get out.

Comment: The general pattern is that you only have 1 central process that fires off more HTTP requests if they are under the threshold, or queues them i they are. Here's another example of an implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-rate-limit